# uClinux "make menuconfig" build error on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, makefile, stm32, uclinux, makemessages

There is quite old **uClinux-dist-20080808** with uClinux-dist-20080808-20090112 and uClinux_on_stm32 patches for **STM32F10x** MCU, as described here [AN3012](https://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/embedded-software/mcu-mpu-embedded-software/stm32-embedded-software/stm32-standard-peripheral-library-expansion/stsw-stm32024.html).

I use Ubuntu 18.04 (inside VirtualBox) to build uClinux and go through AN3012 step-by-step.

So, I run "make menuconfig", enter settings as shown on page 15 (AN3012) and then exit menu. There are a number of messages in terminal and finally I got this:

> configuration written to .config
>
> make[ 2]: Leaving directory '/home/maksim/Projects/STM/uClinux-dist/config' 
>   make[ 1]: Leaving directory '/home/maksim/Projects/STM/uClinux-dist'
>   make[ 1]: Entering directory '/home/maksim/Projects/STM/uClinux-dist' 
>   Makefile:228: *** mixed implicit and normal rules: deprecated syntax
>
> Makefile:245: *** mixed implicit and normal rules: deprecated syntax
>
> KCONFIG_NOTIMESTAMP=1 make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-uclinuxeabi- -C linux-2.6.x menuconfig
>
> make[ 2]: Entering directory '/home/maksim/Projects/STM/uClinux-dist/linux-2.6.x'
>
> Makefile:434: *** mixed implicit and normal rules: deprecated syntax
>
> Makefile:1563: *** mixed implicit and normal rules: deprecated syntax
>
> make[ 2]: *** No rule to make target 'menuconfig'.  Stop.
>
> make[ 2]: Leaving directory '/home/maksim/Projects/STM/uClinux-dist/linux-2.6.x'
>
> Makefile:183: recipe for target 'linux_menuconfig' failed
>
> make[ 1]: *** [linux_menuconfig] Error 2
>
> make[ 1]: Leaving directory '/home/maksim/Projects/STM/uClinux-dist'
>
> Makefile:127: recipe for target 'menuconfig' failed 
>   make: *** [menuconfig] Error 2

**Please help to understand what is wrong and fix it.** Many thanks for any help!

Notes for those who want to reproduce the issue:

1) you need to fix the uCLinux-dist/kconfig/config/zconf.hash.c (insert the snippet below at line 165)

```
#if defined __GNUC_STDC_INLINE__ || defined __GNUC_GNU_INLINE__
    __attribute__ ((__gnu_inline__))
#endif
```

2) uClinux uClinux-dist-20080808 is available [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/uclinux/files/uClinux%20Stable/)

3) uClinux-dist-20080808-20090112 patch is available [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120501030746/http://www.uclinux.org/pub/uClinux/dist/patches/)

4) uClinux_on_stm32 patch is available here [here](https://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/embedded-software/mcu-mpu-embedded-software/stm32-embedded-software/stm32-standard-peripheral-library-expansion/stsw-stm32024.html)

Comment: "mixed implicit and normal rules: deprecated syntax". Seems to be that you make is to new. Older make may accept that Makefile, the current one you use did not. You may can get another ( older ) make?

Comment: I'm not sure about _make_ utility itself (I'm not a Linux expert, sorry). I'll try to use old Ubuntu. Thanks for suggestion)

Comment: @Klaus, you are right - with Ubuntu 12.04.5 "make menuconfig" is successful now. May be, more modern version could be good too, I didn't check. Bootable image build is also successful (but didn't check on MCU). Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to **use older Linux** version. Ubuntu 12.04.5 is OK.

Do not forget to add CodeSourcery /bin folder to PATH.